# How Can I Pass a 404 Error from Model in MVC 4 to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model, http-status-code-404

In my RouteConfig.cs file I have the following to handle my Url requests;

```
routes.MapRoute("Product", "products/{Url}",
new { controller = "product", action = "index" });
```

In my model, I check that the Url entered exists in my database.  However, I want to return a 404 error that the requested page does not exist, if I can't find a match in my database.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller's method, you can return a `HTTP response` like this :

```
if (product == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Also can use the `HttpNotFoundResult`, which is `return HttpNotFound();` from within a controller.

Comment: Am I missing something.  I get Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult'

Comment: Try with the `return HttpNotFound();` like said Steven

Comment: I saw, my old example works only if you return HttpResponseMessage only (for WebApi framework).